# Is there any way to get extra information like as non-follower reach, follower reach,follower growth etc. with using Instagram Graph API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I want to get some metrics with using Instagram Graph API like total numbers of non-followers and followers reach, followers growth and unfollows for my business account. However, no matter how hard I researched, I could not find a source that provided the metrics I specified.

```
https://graph.instagram.com/v12.0/{my_ig_id}/insights?metric=impressions,reach&period=week
https://graph.instagram.com/v12.0/{my_page_id}?fields=business_discovery.username(ig_user_name){followers_count}
```

[total reach counts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZDL6.png)
[total followers count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iyK9.png)

When I specify a URLs like above, I can only get the total reach and follower counts as you can see in the screen shoots. But I want also those metrics like ;

1. reach = 69
2. reach_followers = "some integer"
3. reach_non_followers = "some integer"
4. follower_growth = "some integer"

PS: My Instagram account is integrated with my business account and Facebook page. I have also given ;(ads_management,business_management,instagram_basic,instagram_manage_comments,instagram_manage_insights,pages_read_engagement,public_profile) permissions.

Is there any way to get the metrics I'm talking about? I will be grateful if somebody could help me.